# Which folder to use as default web root?

Tags: magento2, installation, webroot

I see some projects using the Magento 2 root folder as webroot and other projects using the `pub` folder as the web root, independently of using Apache or NGINX, both worked.

Which webroot folder should I use in a new Magento 2 installation and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should you the `pub` folder as webroot, it improves security. The rest of the Magento file system is vulnerable because it is accessible from a browser. Setting the webroot to the pub/ directory prevents site visitors from accessing sensitive areas of the Magento file system from a browser.

For example:

```
/var/www/html/magento2/pub
```

Remember to edit your **env.php** to have this following node:

```
'directories' => [
    'document_root_is_pub' => true
]
```

Reference: [Magento 2 DevDocs - Modify docroot to improve security](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/tutorials/change-docroot-to-pub.html)